# Cannot access functions contract myetherwallet

Tags: myetherwallet

No functions show up when adding [this contract](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x174ae4a8a0b5e70defbcfcbf796ad1aa95f1dd3d#code) to https://www.myetherwallet.com/interface/interact-with-contract. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

MyEtherWallet had a bug, they fixed it recently. The official reply from them was

*"A bug was introduced when we updated interact with contract to handle the changes introduced to the ABI format with the newer solidity versions. We've corrected the issue and write functions should populate the function select dropdown. "*